# Accessing the Popper.js instance of a given DOM element

Tags: javascript, popover, popper.js

I am using [Popper.js](https://popper.js.org/) to position various popovers on my page. Essentially, I am trying to display all file input fields in a small popover because the normal, ugly, non-customizable HTML file input ruins the layout of the page.

I have gotten it to work reasonably well by:

1. Iterating over each `input[type=file]` using JQuery and finding the associated button element,
2. Creating a new Popper instance for each file input using:

```js
const popper = createPopper(buttonElement, fileInputElement, {
  // Various options including a modifier that adjusts the offset of the popover
})
```

3. Attaching a 'click' event handler to the button element that toggles the popover's visibility.

However, I noted [here](https://popper.js.org/docs/v2/tutorial/#performance), in the Popper.js documentation (specifically, the "Tutorial"), that I should be destroying each Popper instance whenever the popover is hidden and reconstructed whenever a popover is displayed; that way, Popper.js is not constantly updating the position of hidden elements. But since I don't have just one popover, I don't really keep track of the Popper instances and thus, can't just call `.destroy()` on them.

One possible solution would be if there was a way to access the Popper instance based on the popover element (in this specific case, the `input[type=file]` element). Is there a way to do this? I've seen this sort of idea around the Internet sometimes; for example, one page seemed to indicate that I could do `fileInputElement.popperInstance` to access the Popper instance. Unfortunately, this did not work (and neither did `fileInputElement._popperInstance`).

Any ideas?